# How to reorder dataframe series number after droping the null value

Tags: pandas, data-science

```
>>> df
       name        toy       born
0    Alfred        NaN        NaN
1    Batman  Batmobile 1940-04-25
2  Catwoman   Bullwhip        NaN

# Serial number starts from 0
```

In this dataframe, we observe that the serial number (first column) is 0,1,2. After dropping the null value, we have:

```
     name        toy       born
1  Batman  Batmobile 1940-04-25


# Serial number starts from 1 (should start from 0)
```

I was wondering how can we reset Batman's serial number back to 0? Obviously, Pandas just delete the row with null value, but it did not reset the serial number. Are there any ways to solve this problem?

Comment: add `.reset_index(drop=True)` to the end of your method call

Comment: Thank you! @Datanovice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.dropna(subset= ['toy', 'born']).reset_index()
```